# How to chown/chmod after tag checkout in git?

Tags: git, git-checkout, git-tag

On a live environment I need to fetch tags and simply switch between them. After every switch, I need to chown/chmod all files inside the worktree.

I've created a `post-checkout` hook

```
#!/bin/bash
chown -R www-data:www-data public/
find public/ -type f -exec chmod 400 {} \;
find public/ -type d -exec chmod 500 {} \;
```

The `.git` dir is outside of the public dir, so I've added the following to the git config.

```
worktree = /var/www/site/public
```

Now I execute the following commands

```
# git fetch --tags
# git checkout 0.0.1
```

But the `post-checkout` hook does not get executed. Whats wrong?

Another question: What is the relative path of the hook? Is it the same dir where `.git` lies or is it `public/`?

Comment: Does it work when you run the hook directly? i.e. ./post-checkout ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that your `.git/hooks/post-checkout` has executable flag set, otherwise do `chmod +x .git/hooks/post-checkout`.
Current working directory of a hook as a repository root (the directory where `.git` is located).

You can verify that you hook is actually executed and also its current working directory by writing a very simple hook

```
#!/bin/sh
pwd
echo "This is post-checkout hook"
```

Comment: Thanks, the excute bit made the trick. PS. when settings worktree config, the raltive path of the hook will not be the same dir as .git, but the worktree path.